# VIM: Replace [aeiou]' with the respective accented letter

Tags: vim, digraphs

I know that VIM support digraph, and it would be perfect if it's possible to use with `:s` command, but I can't find a way to use it!

I think something like:

```
:%s/\([aeiouAEIOU]\)'/\=digraph(submatch(1)."!")/g
```

Would be perfect, but I didn't find a `digraph` function.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Ok, after a bit of diggin in the built-in VIM's functions, I've found `tr` and a first solution to the problem:

```
:%s/\([aeiouAEIOU]\)'/\=tr(submatch(1), 'aeiouAEIOU', 'àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ')/g
```

However, I still want to know if there's a way to use `digraph` in expressions :)

Comment: You probably want to add `c` at the end to confirm, or do you want to replace every vowel in your document ?

Comment: Not everyone, only vowels followed by `'`. In Italy some people have the bad habit to writes the accented vowel as `a'`, especially the uppercase ones (Window is to blame: no easy way for them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function! Digraph(letter, type)
    silent exec "normal! :let l:s = '\<c-k>".a:letter.a:type."'\<cr>"
    return l:s
endfunction
```

This function will allow you to generate any digraph you want.

It simulates typing `<c-k><char><char>` by running it with the normal command and assigning it to the local variable s. And then it returns s.

After this function is defined and you can use it like this.

```
:%s/\([aeiouAEIOU]\)'/\=Digraph(submatch(1), "!")/g
```

Note: This was based off of the source code for [EasyDigraph](https://github.com/vim-scripts/EasyDigraph.vim)

Comment: A small typo: in the `:s` command, the call to Digraph should be `Digraph(submatch(1), "!")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using a hand-coded vim function (add to your vimrc):

```
" get a matching digraph for a given ASCII character
function! GetDigraph(var1)
   "incomplete dictionary of digraphs, add your own....
   let DigDict = {'a': 'à', 'e': 'è', 'i': 'ì'}
   "get the matching digraph.  If no match, just return the given character
   let DictEntry = get(DigDict, a:var1, a:var1)
   return DictEntry
endfunction
```

Call it like this `:%s/\([aeiouAEIOU]\)'/\=GetDigraph(submatch(1))/g`

Comment: If I understand lazel correctly, I think (s)he's wanting programmatic access to `digraph-table`, which is pretty expansive.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to access this except via simulating keystrokes to type Ctrl-K <digraph char 1> <digraph char 2>.